# Problem with finding minimum and maximum values in C

Tags: c

I have an issue in finding the maximum and minimum value in an array with 31 objects.

I tried to find the maximum and minimum value by putting an if statement in a for statement, as it is below. Also, I wanted to find the sum of all values of the array, but none of these three targets was finally successful

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double july[30], a, b, c;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &july[i]);
        a = a + july[i];
        if (july[i + 1] <= july[i]) {
            b = july[i + 1];
        } else
        if (july[i + 1] >= july[i]) {
            c = july[i + 1];
        }
    }
    printf("%lf\n%lf", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I write all the values into the array, but in the end the result is a void, having an output of: "Process exited after 14.42 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . ." and nothing else

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `for(i=0;i<31;i++){` will go outside the range of `july[30]`

Comment: `a`, `b`, and  `c` are not good variable names.  Use something more descriptive.

Comment: Also, the `printf` is only printing two out of three passed variables.

Comment: ALso check _scanf_ returns 1 to know if the input was a valid double

Comment: ALso `july[i+1]` can access out of the array or in the best case to a non initialized value

Comment: keep your solutions simple when learning. do the total and min max searching in different loops. It will be more clear what is happening.

Comment: Oh, I'am sorry, I forgot, I did it moments ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `double july[30]` the valid indexes are from 0 up to 29 but having `for(i=0;i<31;i++)` the forms `july[i]` access to the indexes up to 30 and the forms `july[i+1]` access to the indexes up to 31, with an undefined behavior.

Furthermore inside the loop only the entries from 0 up to *i* can be set, so the forms `july[i+1]` access in the best case to a non initialized entry of the array. Out of that doing

> ```
> if(july[i+1]<=july[i]){
>     b=july[i+1];
>     }
> else if(july[i+1]>=july[i]){
>     c=july[i+1];
> ```

does not allow to find the min/max, you need to compare the new entry with *b* and *c*

Just above I said *can be set* because you do not check the value return by *scanf*, if a non double representation is enter *scanf* stops definitively to set the entries, in case of an error you need to flush the invalid input and to redo the *scanf*.

In `printf("%lf\n%lf",a,b,c);` you want to print 3 values ( sum, min and max ) so a *%lf* is missing in the format.

---

A proposal can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  double july[30];
  double sum = 0;
  double min = INFINITY;
  double max = -INFINITY;

  for (size_t i = 0; i != (sizeof(july) / sizeof(july[0])); ++i) {
    printf("enter value #%zu : ", i);

    while (scanf("%lf", &july[i]) != 1) {
      fputs("invalid value, reenter it : ", stderr);
      /* flush all the line */
      int c;

      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF) {
          fputs("end of file, abort\n", stderr);
          return -1;
        }
      }
    }

    sum += july[i];

    if(july[i] < min)
      min = july[i];
    if (july[i] > max)
      max = july[i];
  }

  printf("sum=%f\nmin=%f\nmax=%f\n", sum, min, max);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter value #0 : 1
enter value #1 : 4
enter value #2 : 2
enter value #3 : 5
enter value #4 : 88
enter value #5 : 78
enter value #6 : 12
enter value #7 : 11
enter value #8 : 3
enter value #9 : -5
enter value #10 : 12 
enter value #11 : 1
enter value #12 : 1
enter value #13 : 1
enter value #14 : 1
enter value #15 : 1
enter value #16 : 1
enter value #17 : 1
enter value #18 : 1
enter value #19 : 1
enter value #20 : 1
enter value #21 : 1
enter value #22 : 1
enter value #23 : 1
enter value #24 : aze
invalid value, reenter it : 1
enter value #25 : 1
enter value #26 : 1
enter value #27 : 1
enter value #28 : 1
enter value #29 : 1
sum=230.000000
min=-5.000000
max=88.000000
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As you can see

- I name the variable from their behavior making the code more clear, contrarily to *a, b* and *c*
- the right type for an index is `size_t`
- I do not use a literal integer but I use *sizeof* in the *for* to follow the size of the array even if it is changed
- I use `INFINITY` to initialize *min* because any valid *double* is lower that it, and `-INFINITY` to initialize *max* because any valid *double* is greater that it
- in case of an invalid input on *scanf* I flush all the line before to redo, you can also just read a word if you prefer
- in the *printf* you do not need the 'l' because *printf* cannot receive a *float* whose are transformed to *double* (but the 'l' is necessary in *scanf* to read a *double*)

Comment: From the problem statement by the OP, the array size should be `31`. Using an array is not even required, a simple `double` variable would suffice. The OP is probably expected to write 2 separate loops: one to read the values into an array, and a second one to compute the sum, min and max of the values in the array, where the initial values are easier to determine (use the first element of the array).

Comment: Another interesting point to address is whether NaN values should produce NaN results or be ignored...

Comment: @chqrlie hello, cela faisait longtemps, tu as diminué ton activité ici, ceci dit moi aussi et plus ça va plus je pense carrément arrêter, j'ai un certain raz le bol de certaines pratiques ...

Comment: Bonjour Bruno, l'activité est assez variable, comme l'intérêt des questions :)